# How to configure RestClientProxyFactoryBean in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring

Please help. How to configure RestClientProxyFactoryBean in spring boot project

Thx

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See this example: It creates a rest client service which you can call to get a rest client instance to make http calls

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=expressui-framework-master/expressui-domain/src/main/java/com.expressui.domain/RestClientService.java

Usage of this can be seen in the Below link:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=expressui-framework-master/expressui-domain/src/main/java/com.expressui.domain/RestClientService.java#

And some test case to be run can be found here:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=expressui-framework-master/expressui-domain/src/main/java/com.expressui.domain/RestClientService.java#

**Explanation:**

So basically we can create different Restclients using proxyfactory bean. In the above example, a service named Geoplanetservice is being created. Rest communication happens via GeoPlanetClient service Interface which is the instantiated via our proxyfactory bean.

Comment: coo. Thx man! But just one question. What exactly is ServiceInterface? it is being set in the factory object. Is it custom class which we have to create or is it possible to provide default one?

Comment: @Pavan Updated the answer. If you will look in the example directory checkout GeoPlanet service and its testcase in test directory. It should be self explanatory. Do accept the answer if its helps you

Comment: downvote: I would have loved to see the solution myself but links are broken. I guess that is why they say not to put an answer that consists solely of links?